# How do I get automagic convertions from Rust Into trait?

Tags: rust

I have a struct `Object` for which I have many implementations of `From` (including `isize` and `&str`). I got the sense from [this article where `Into` is described as 'genius'](https://llogiq.github.io/2015/07/30/traits.html) that things could get automatically converted for me. I've incorporated the suggestions that people have made, and made something that is standalone in the [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=df5c0bef3271414798d7944cd9251b19) but it still gets a couple of errors.

```rust
#[derive(Copy,Clone)]
pub union Object {
    d:f64,
    i:isize,
}
impl From<isize> for Object {
    fn from(i:isize) -> Self {
        Object{i}
    }
}
impl From<f64> for Object {
    fn from(d:f64) -> Self {
        Object{d}
    }
}
pub fn old_convert(foo: Object, _elements: &[Object]) -> Object {
    foo
}
pub fn new_convert<'a,T>(foo: impl Into<Object>, elements: &'a [T]) -> Object
where
    &'a T: Into<Object>,
    Object: From<T>,
{
    let mut el = Vec::new();
    for o in elements.iter() {
        el.push(o.into())
    }
    old_convert(foo.into(),&el)
}

#[test]
fn testOldConvert() {
    old_convert(Object::from(42), &[Object::from(3.1415)]);
}
#[test]
fn testNewConvert() {
    new_convert(42, &[3.1415]);
}
```

So you can see what I currently do. I'd like to not have to include all the `Object::from(...)` when I use my function.
There is 1 error, and 1 problem:

1. I don't know how to implement the `From` it's asking for
2. I don't want to create the temporary vector... surely there's some zero-cost abstraction that allows me to pass the converted array along

Comment: probably going to need to collect into a `Vec` as well if its supposed to be passed as a slice

Comment: I understand that it's obvious to you, but for us it's still hard to tell what `new_convert()` is supposed to be doing. `old_convert()` was returning a pair of an object and a slice of objects, making use of the fact that it received a slice of objects. `new_convert()` returns a pair of... an object and the _last_ element of the slice? Is that the intended behavior? The other issue is that the slice contains _references_ to `T`, and your `From` provides conversions from owned values.

Comment: To create something that works like `old_convert()` I'd go with a signature that accepts and returns a `Vec`, as in [this modification](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=7a3810ada383635936f4a880347db4e9). (`impl Into<...>` is basically an anonymous generic.) You can make it even a bit more general, [as shown here](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=20740c4db2e87a32a0df5e8a5ed72236), and accept any iterable, including  vectors but also arrays etc. Hope some of these help with what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Thanks @user4815162342 I appreciate your help. Sorry my example wasn't very understandable, and I was iterating the code example to try to get my "real" question answered without adding ridiculous amounts of detail... but as I used your suggestions, I got closer. I don't need to actually return the collection... so the example I have now is closer... I need to iterate through it.  I really appreciate your help, but if you could answer as an "answer" rather than comment, I could give you credit for the help. `old_convert` is only useful in terms of the types and how it's called

Comment: Ahhh... I get that using `foo: impl Into<Object>` solves my second problem. Now just the more important one: the trait `From<&_>` is not implemented for `Object`

Comment: If you only need to iterate over objects, then `old_convert()` doesn't really need a slice, but an iterator over `Object`s. If you can modify `old_convert()`, perhaps [something like this](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=d227d588fcdf0270cb9e22976ef96d85) would work? If not, i.e. if `old_convert()` insists on receiving a *slice* of `Object`s, then I'm afraid you'll have to use temporary allocation because `new_convert()` is simply not receiving such a slice, so it'd have to create one.